# gnu make put include path into make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My include file references many other make files using something like:

> `include Enablers/MSRP/Android.mk`

the problem is that the make file that references all other makefiles is deep in sub-folders, or, in other words the correct path would be something like:

> `include ../../../../../Enablers/MSRP/Android.mk`

In order for me to build my makefile I have to add ../../../../.. to make search path:

> `ndk-build -I../../../../.. -j8 other params...`

(ndk-build is a wrapper for gnu make on android buildsystem, it's equivalent to make build-local.mk other params)

So, what can i do to to avoid adding the `../../../../..` to make search path? I could go the makefile and update all makefile include statements, but I'm looking for the way to add that extra include path at the top of my makefile. Something like:

```
makeincludepaht += include Enablers/MSRP/Android.mk
include Enablers/MSRP/Android.mk
...
```

Comment: The `-I` method is probably best. You can put the path at the top of your makefile, but that will marry the makefile to your directory structure. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: You can always create soft links from your deep directory to some top level and reference that in your makefile. The drawback is that without the links, your builds will fail so you'd need to create a script to automate the creation of the links if you want to share your makefile with others.

Comment: @Beta: what's the -I method that you are talking about? Is it something that I need to put on command line or inside makefile itself? I'm ok to marry for that directory structure by the way, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: not going to work, I need this s%it working on windows as well (in regular cmd)

Comment: If you're ok with hard dependencies in regards to actual hard disk layout, you should be able to send a variable to make that contains the top level directory and use that to construct the rest in your makefile. This way there is no need for elaborate `..\..\..` usage.

Comment: I already pass to make the ../../.. on cmd line, but the goal is to avoid passing anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the new include path to the standard search path:

```
.INCLUDE_DIRS += ../../..
```

[Look at the end of the Special Variables section for the `.INCLUDE_DIRS` special variable.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, at least with GNU make 4.1. The manual also says nothing about setting `.INCLUDE_DIRS`, only that it contains the include search path, not that you can set it. Did you test this solution?

Comment: I see you answered your own question here, so I'll assume it worked for you (and that you must have tested it). What version of GNU make did you use?

Comment: @camh I don't remember context, which means after I've fixed it I never cam back to it. Linked docs describe what it does, that's exactly what I needed. Just to make it clear and avoid confusion: this is include search path for make to include other make files, has nothing to do with c/c++ include paths

Comment: For the sake of recording history, this answer does not work with gnu make 4.1. `mkdir foo; printf ".INCLUDE_DIRS += foo\ninclude bar.mk\n" >Makefile; printf "all: ; @echo in bar.mk\n" > foo/bar.mk; make` results in `Makefile:2: bar.mk: No such file or directory`. `make -I foo` does work. My point about the linked docs is that they do not say that changing `.INCLUDE_DIRS` actually changes the search path. The docs only say that `.INCLUDE_DIRS` expands to the search path.

Comment: @camh you are correct. From quick search it also looks like it always was read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ndk-build, but I have similar setup. I just set a variable in make that contains this path and then use that variable in all my includes.
makefile: 

`INCLUDE_TOP=../../../../..

include $(INCLUDE_TOP)/someDir/includes.mk`

You can also then use INCLUDE_TOP inside includes.mk for all your paths. It is usually better to make it default to some value by conditionally setting in there.
includes.mk:

`# will only set if not already set

INCLUDE_TOP ?= ./

HEADERS=$(INCLUDE_TOP)/headers`

Comment: It's not going to work. The reason is that files that sit in different levels will also reference relative to that ../../../.. but another level it will be already wrong folder. For this solution to work I'd need to modify lots of make files and convert that ../../.. to absolute path.